# java mysql insert syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get an syntax error at con=createConnection(); in netbeans ide, i want to insert records to a mysql database. how can correct this??

```
private void btnlogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

         user=txtuser.getText();
      char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
             String passString=new String(pass);
            **![con =createConnection();][1]**
             try{    

String str="INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + passString + "')";
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(str); 
statement.setString(1,user);
    statement.setString(2,passString);
statement.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
            }

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Stock?"+
                                   "user=root&password=";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `con` and do you have createConnection() static method that will give you connection ?

```
con =createConnection();
```

If you are using `PreparedStatement` and setting parameters you should have placeholder in query like this

```
String str = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Comment: please help me. i want to insert records in the button click event.

Comment: I am using netbeans and i want to insert records in the button click event. isn't there a easy wy to do so??

Comment: its pretty easy, you just need to understand jdbc by googling (as said) the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 String str="INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES (?,?)";
 java.sql.PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(str); 
 statement.setString(1,user);
 statement.setString(2,passString);
 statement.executeUpdate();
```